# How to download HLS stream into a local machine?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Sometimes it is useful to download a stream into our local machine.

Reasons could be

- To make a manual modification to the manifest
- For getting fast access to files of a server with poor networking.

If we try to use `curl` or `wget` to download the asset which is pointed by the URL for the stream, we end up downloading a small text file. It is surely not the video asset.

So how can we download the stream itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual script which does the download is given in the link at the bottom of my answer. But before we proceed to the how-to, let's first understand the steps for downloading a stream.

Without going into too much details, the URL pointing to the stream is typically named with the **m3u8** extension. That file is called the *manifest* of the stream and is actually a text file containing, among other things, a list of pairs: a bitrate and a corresponding URL for the matching *playlist* file. Here is an excerpt from a **manifest** file:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=380600,CODECS="avc1.4d00c,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=320x180
http://f24hls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/221193-b/F24_EN_LO_HLS/master_250.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=655600,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
http://f24hls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/221193/F24_EN_LO_HLS/master_500.m3u8
```

A playlist file is another text file which tell the player which TS file is to be playing on each position of the playback head.

Here is the beginning of a typical **playlist** file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:303165
#EXTINF:10.000,
20170216T114458/master_500/00151/master_500_01165.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
20170216T114458/master_500/00151/master_500_01166.ts
```

So after downloading the playlist file for each of the bitrates, we can start downloading the TS files required to play the stream at each of the possible bitrates.

All this is done using a quite simple and self-explaining script which I was putting in GitHub: https://github.com/ishahak/HLS_Downloader

I hope it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ffmpeg. Like this:

```
fmpeg -i "http://somewhere.com/video.m3u8" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Comment: This will download the content as mp4, not the HLS together with its data files